How to consolidate multiple entities with the same primary key as one during insert using Entity Framework Core?
I'm creating an application that fetches Entra ID applications with owners from MS Graph.
The application maps each Entra ID application to an Application entity, with the owners being mapped to Owner entities that refer back to the application.
The problem is that once all Entra ID applications have been processed, many of the Application entities hold Owner entities with the same primary key, leading to an error on SaveChangesAsync():
var applicationEntities = (await _assetOwnershipRepository.GetApplicationsAsync(includeOwners: true)).ToList();
var graphApplications = (await GetApplicationsAsync()).ToList();

graphApplications.ForEach(ua =>
{
    var applicationEntity = applicationEntities.FirstOrDefault(a => string.Equals(a.Id.ToString(), ua.Id, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (applicationEntity is null)
    {
        var application = _mapper.Map<Application>(ua);
        _assetOwnershipRepository.AddApplicationsAsync(new[] {application});
        return;
    }
        
    _mapper.Map(ua, applicationEntity);
});

How would I ensure that all Owners with the same primary key being treated as one during the insert?
Application entity:
public class Application
{
    [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required] public Guid AppId { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(256)] public string DisplayName { get; set; } = default!;
    public ICollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; } = new List<Owner>();
}

Owner entity:
public class Owner
{
    [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required] [MaxLength(256)] public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
    [Required] [MaxLength(256)] public string UserPrincipalName { get; set; } = default!;
    [Required] [MaxLength(256)] public string Email { get; set; } = default!;
}


Do not use List.ForEach if you have async calls. It may cause errors, because tasks are not awaited. Use simple foreach operator and await all async calls - await _assetOwnershipRepository.AddApplicationsAsync

@SvyatoslavDanyliv Couldn't I make the List.ForEach take an async lambda?

It is not possible to work correctly with async calls via List.ForEach. Similar question

Fetch the owners from the DbContext and associate them. If there is the possibility that new owners could be added as part of the iteration, that is fine, the new owner can be inserted with the first application that references it. You can either keep your own list of owners or use EF's tracking cache to avoid the extra reference handling. If using a Repository that's simpler to track the owners yourself:
For instance:
var applicationEntities = (await _assetOwnershipRepository.GetApplicationsAsync(includeOwners: true)).ToList();
var graphApplications = (await GetApplicationsAsync()).ToList();
var updatedOwnerIds = graphApplications.Select(ua => ua.OwnerId).ToList();

var owners = _assetOwnershipRepository.GetOwnersById(updatedOwnerIds);
// essentially _context.Owners.Where(o => updatedOwnerIds.Contains(o.OwnerId)).ToList();

graphApplications.ForEach(ua =>
{
    var applicationEntity = applicationEntities.FirstOrDefault(a => string.Equals(a.Id.ToString(), ua.Id, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (applicationEntity is null)
    {
        var application = _mapper.Map<Application>(ua);
        var existingOwner = owners.FirstOrdefault(o => o.OwnerId = ua.OwnerId);
        if(existingOwner != null)
             application.Owner = existingOwner;
        else
             owners.Add(application.Owner); // Next statement will see it added and associated to DbContext.
        _assetOwnershipRepository.AddApplicationsAsync(new[] {application});
        return;
    }
    
    if (ua.OwnerId != applicationEntity.OwnerId)
    {
        var owner = owners.First(o => o.OwnerId == ua.OwnerId);
         applicationEntity.Owner = owner;
    }
    _mapper.Map(ua, applicationEntity); // Ensure does not attempt to alter applicationEntity.Owner.
});

What this essentially does is fetch the current updated set of owners from the DbContext. When you map your new application we first check if we have a reference to an existing owner and if so, associate it. If the owner is a new instance we add it to the list of known owners if the AddApplication will result in inserting this as a new owner. If we insert 2 applications with the same new owner then the next application will pick up that same reference. This assumes new owners would have client-side IDs generated. Otherwise if we are updating an application we check if the owner ID changed, and if so, associate the new tracked owner.
When dealing with the DbContext directly you can do the same thing via:
_context.Owners.Where(o => updatedOwnerIds.Contains(o.OwnerId)).ToList();

Here we don't actually need to capture the list of results, this will still load them into EF's tracking cache. Then to check the tracking cache:
var existingOwner = _context.Owners.Local.FirstOrDefault(o => o.OwnerId == ua.OwnerId);

When it comes to references that are expected to point to existing rows you can use Attach(applicationEntity.Owner) on the DbContext to tell EF to track this entity as a reference to an existing row rather than a new row to be inserted. However, when attaching references that might link to existing tracked entities you should always check the tracking cache (.Local) to avoid runtime exceptions if the Context happens to already be tracking a reference with the same ID.

Thank you. Are you sure, that EF Core would start tracking the new owner, if I add it to a retrieved collection, like owners.Add(application.Owner)?

The example doesn't make 100% sense, as updatedOwners.First(o => o.OwnerId == ua.OwnerId) is not defined anywhere

Is _context.Owners.Local a reference to the local tracking cache of the owner entities, that I can perform operations on, like FirstOrDefault() without executing queries against the database?

I corrected the example, that should have been owners.First not updatedOwners.First. Yes, if I add an application which has a reference to a new Owner will see the owner inserted and tracked. Using .Local does query the local tracking cache for references without hitting the database.

Thank you, I believe you example should be application.Owner = existingOwner;

Fixed. was a little muddled writing that out rather than a copy-paste from VS. :)
